# Is there a way in Java to make all extended classes a Singleton?

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, singleton

I have a very specific case.
I need to develop a public API for my software, and I have a class, let's say **`Base`, which extends the `Listener`** class (that comes from an external API). Now, **any specific class users will create will extend `Base`**, so it will also extend `Listener`.

**I** also **want that the user can't instantiate multiple times the same class if it extends `Base`** - a Listener is used in a static context by other classes and instantiating it multiple times is useless, can cause memory leaks in the software itself and even duplicate events called. I myself don't instantiate `Listener`(s) multiple times, but external users can do it and it would be hard to tell them to just stop because my software works by thinking that their class behaves like a Singleton.

**Is there a way to say that any class that extends `Base` should be a Singleton?**

Making the `Base` class a Singleton itself is useless, because `Base` is extended from multiple classes and `Base` itself is never going to be instantiated anyways. I just need a way to make that all classes that extends `Base` should be forced to be Singleton or in any way only have a single instance.

I could also make the `Base` class an abstract one, but how would I impose the fact that there should be only a single instance for each class which extends `Base` at a time?

e.g.
Three classes extends `Base`: `Child1`, `Child2`, `Child3`. All three should be Singletons and be instanced only a single time.

Comment: There's no way to enforce that in Java alone.  Dependency injection could help, although you'd have to mark each extended class a singleton.  Although you could write a build time hook that checks all classes and throws an error if one is not set up as a singleton (has a public constructor or has no static getInstance if derived from your base class).

Comment: @GabeSechan The build time hook would be a nice idea, thanks! I'll see if someone has a better one, otherwise I'll try it, even if it's a bit hacky.

Comment: Well, you could define `Base` an enum, with `Child1`,`Child2` and `Child3` as enum values. The user can't define subtypes of their own, and all instances are eager singletons, and implicitly anonymous sublasses of `Base`. I suppose that is as close as you can get to your requirements.

Comment: @Hulk well the fact is, I need that the user can define classes on their own, so I don't think that would be fine, but thanks anyways!

Comment: it seems unclear how much sense the design makes. maybe better to avoid letting anyone subclass the singleton, and instead supply strategy classes or lambdas or something customizing different behaviors. even if the singleton inheritance worked like you want, it  could give the users too much power, while leaving you with a fragile base class problem.

Comment: you could use a Map as Singleton and get Child Instances from there (including creation as Singleton children)...

Comment: @NathanHughes what do you mean? In my case, any class that extends `Listener` should have custom methods which have the `@EventListener` decorator and they use the custom methods to listen to events. So, practically, I can't do it using lambdas or "callbacks" style. What do you mean when saying Strategy Classes?

Comment: @TraianGEICU that would make sense! Thanks, I'll try it ASAP. I didn't even think of it.

Comment: it should work, have to do something similar once ... have fun !